# Emacs dired slow on cygwin

Tags: performance, emacs, cygwin

Emacs 24.3 dired listing on cygwin is horribly slow (xemacs is very fast).  At one time I had fixed this but can't remember what it was.  Does anyone have a quick fix for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "on Cygwin"? Do you mean that your Emacs is Cygwin Emacs, i.e., built by Cygwin? Or do you mean that you use ordinary Emacs (e.g. GNU Emacs) and you also have Cygwin installed? Beyond this, you will likely need to provide (a lot) more info, if you want someone to be able to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: (setq directory-free-space-program nil) ;; add to your .emacs file. It's because df runs so slowly on NT fs.

Comment: Johan: you should have put your suggestion as an answer. My direds are now much faster -- thank you!